# How to send string messages via bluetooth in flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to send messages between two phones via bluetooth
I am using [flutter_blue_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_plus) package and i am not understanding on how to send string messages and receive them, what characteristic to use or descriptor or service.

If its possible i want to listen to the messages received by the other device connected via bluetooth.

I also wanted to know if [nearby connections api](https://pub.dev/packages/nearby_connections) can be use to connect phones to bluetooth low energy devices?
i want to try both since bluetooth low energy is the priority, i am skeptical about nearby connection api.

```
D/uuid    (17373): 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
I/flutter (17373): STATE_CONNECTED
W/BluetoothAdapter(17373): getBluetoothService() called with no 
BluetoothManagerCallback
D/STATUS_CONNECT(17373): java.io.IOException: read failed, socket 
might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
I/flutter (17373): FC:02:96:56:FE:55
I/flutter (17373): STATE_DISCONNECTED
```

Why am i getting disconnected as soon as i connect? is that because of my phone? I am trying to connect to my other phone
also is i think thats the reason its throwing read failed exception

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using flutter Bluetooth serial, then I recommend you to use github repository recommended by flutter.dev
https://github.com/edufolly/flutter_bluetooth_serial

and if you want to send message then go to examples/lib/chatpage.dart
there you can send any message using

```
_sendMessage("Hello World");
```

or you can just send messages using

```
_sendMessage("Hello World");
```